# Extracting many .tar files fast

Tags: windows, compression, zip, tar, 7-zip

I have a directory with about 400 tar files.  Each file holds between 10 and 1 million .json files that are about 5kb each.  I am working on a Windows 2016 server over AWS with pretty good specs.

If I grab the bunch and hit extract with 7zip, it appears to be excruciatingly slow.  I'm wondering is there is any meaningful way to speed up this process?

7zip does not seem to be using anywhere near 50% of the processor power or ram.  However running a second instance of 7zip does not seem to speed up performance.

Comment: Sounds like you are I/O limited.  7-zip also doesn't sound to be multiple-threaded

Comment: And perhaps limited by the FS. 1 million tiny files already isn't Windows' favourite thing, but if they're also all in the same directory, it's hopeless.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Why is this something windows cant handle?  And why is it a problem for them to be in the same directory?

Comment: every new file needs to be written to the master file table (MFT), listing where it is physically located on the disk, and also written to disk. If you are extracting millions of files, your hard disk will be working pretty hard going back and forward between updating the MFT and writing the extracted files. You can probably check disk usage using Resource Monitor. If the disk is at 100%, you won't be able to get the process to go faster

Comment: Please share us with quantity, type, and configuration of disks that are installed on your Windows 2016 server

Comment: I don't have those specs easily available--but I can confirm it was an I/O limit.  Looking inside resource monitor confirms that the disk is being fully utilized.  Thanks for all the help!